# Maven - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jersey-client

I added a client jar of project A to project B. 
They both have different versions of jersey and jackson apis. Both java 8. 
When I bring up the Application , it works fine. All dependencies are resolved and endpoints work fine. 
But when I run integration tests, I get below error

```
     244509 [pool-1-thread-5] INFO  [] com.mycom.salesforce.client.rest.jersey.filter.RetryFilter  - Error connecting to Salesforce. Attempt: 1 of 2
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
        at com.mycom.salesforce.client.rest.jersey.filter.RetryFilter.handle(RetryFilter.java:41)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:694)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$300(WebResource.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:576)
        at com.mycom.salesforce.client.rest.jersey.BasicRestClientJerseyImpl.post(BasicRestClientJerseyImpl.java:59)
```

There are bunch of dependencies that have different versions, not sure which one specifically I should look into. Should I exclude any specific classes from the client jar ? Why do only tests have issues.

Comment: This cannot be a problem with dependencies, this seems to be the certificate issue with the endpoint you are calling( may be the endpoint url is  having self-signed certificate) .

Comment: @sampathpremarathna The develop branch works fine but it's just my branch that has this issue. How do I fix it if the endpoints have self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i fixed it by changing the sdk. I downloaded java8 from open JDK and the problem was fixed. Downloaded from this link --> https://openjdk.java.net/install/